# how can I apply UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad to this?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I already did one for the other hud but this code I don't have a clue

```
for (int i=0; i < hud.lives; i++) {
        SKTextureAtlas *atlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"Sprites"];
        SKTexture *hlife = [atlas textureNamed:@"HUD_life_1"];
        SKSpriteNode *lifeBar = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:hlife];
        lifeBar.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Life%d",i+1];

        [hud addChild:lifeBar];

        if (lastLifeBar == nil ) {
            lifeBar.position = CGPointMake(catHead.position.x+30, catHead.position.y);
        } else {
            lifeBar.position = CGPointMake(lastLifeBar.position.x+10, lastLifeBar.position.y);
        }

        lastLifeBar = lifeBar;
    }
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I wanted to implement UIUserInterfaceIdiompad cause the position on iPad is messed up but on iPhone it's well positioned. I positioned the 1st hud properly on iPad and iPhone but i cannot do it on life bar hud. Here is what i used on 1st hud:          if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        catHead.position = CGPointMake(60, -20);
    }else {
        catHead.position = CGPointMake(30, -10);

    }

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a simple macro like this:

This one will check (compile time)if the current device is an iPad and return yes if so, no otherwise:

```
#define IS_IPAD() ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
```

Here, U can set you wanted height which uses the above macro. If the current device is an iPad the value will be 55, otherwise 44:

```
#define MY_HEIGHT  (IS_IPAD() ? 55 : 40)
```

And take this one as a bonus ;) :

This one will check (compile time) if the current device is an iPhone5/iPhone5c/iPhone5s and return yes if so, no otherwise:

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height == 568 )
```

Comment: I am sorry i'm a newbie in objective-c and I have not used macro in my codes so I really don't know how to implement it.

Comment: See my explanations above, does it helps?

Comment: No it did not work for me. But i am sure your code is ok.

Comment: Why? what is the problem?

Comment: I try implementing it but i don't know where to insert IS_IPAD afterwards also this code works better but is still have a problem with catHead here is the code i used:         if (lastLifeBar == nil) {
lifeBar.position = CGPointMake(catHead.position.x+30, catHead.position.y);
}else if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
lifeBar.position = CGPointMake(lastLifeBar.position.x+20, lastLifeBar.position.y);
} else {
lifeBar.position = CGPointMake(lastLifeBar.position.x+10, lastLifeBar.position.y);
        }
        lastLifeBar = lifeBar;
    }